# Confused when installing orocrm, crm application vs platform application

Tags: crm, orocrm

Never before he had installed an application as Orocrm, and indeed am very confused.

I found 2 Orocrm applications, one is the crm and the other is the platform do not understand anything, I missed.

What are the most tide me folder structures not finish them understand and do not know how they work, if someone could give me a hand, I appreciate it.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Oro Platform is not an application *per se,* it's an application platform that contains most of the basic business application features, such as user management, role management, basic entity CRUD, etc. OroCRM is built on top of Oro Platform and therefore includes all platform bundles in addition to CRM bundles.

If you are having trouble with installation, please check our [installation guide](https://www.orocrm.com/documentation/index/current/book/installation).

I might also suggest you ask further questions at our [forums](https://www.orocrm.com/forums), since we do not actively monitor Stack Overflow on the regular basis.

Thank you for your interest in Oro Platform!

Comment: Thanks for your answer, the tutorial I see, it seems I have to install it in a vps from scratch.

I currently have a panel manager, orocrm could run smoothly?

Comment: I think it should.